# OS: Parrot OS (hashcat : Depends: libminizip1t64 but it is not installable)

Tags: installation, package, parrot-os, depends, hashcat

[Having an issue with Hashcat on Parrot OS Version 6.0 codename: Lory] Please check the screenshot for more clarification, Thank for you the help in advance (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFbyR.png)

tried to install the alternatives for package (libminizip1t64) haven't work!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.